# Recovering the python files after uninstalling Anaconda

Tags: installation, python, uninstall, anaconda

I had an issue with my computer so i had to reinstall my packages including python (Anaconda). I did not realise that when Anaconda gets uninstalled in the computer it deletes all files under `C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3` so i stupidly lost all python codes (how silly i should have been more careful). I am assuming there is no possibility of recovering the deleted python files but i wanted to ask anyway if there is a possibility to do so? Someone suggested to use the disk utility but iam not sure how to recover the files through that.

Many Thanks

Comment: Follow standard file recovery procedures. Also, start making regular backups.

Comment: i tried to recover from file history but it says File history is off. I played around with 'backup and restore' but could not see anything promising

Comment: Backups have to be configured and enabled before you need them. Now you need data recovery, not restoration from backups.

Comment: Thank you. In Settings/Recovery: I have three options:  (1) Reset this PC (2) go back to the previous version of Windows 10 (not avail) (3) Advanced start up. There is no Data recovery option.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device

Comment: I dont think your link applies to me. I read it all